# Only network with loss packet ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

When i connect my notebokk in wi-fi of my house i have high packet loss. But when i change for my phone network i dont have loss packet

```
PING github.com (140.82.112.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=3087 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=2063 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=5 ttl=49 time=1039 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=6 ttl=49 time=156 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=7 ttl=49 time=139 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=8 ttl=49 time=155 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=9 ttl=49 time=249 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=10 ttl=49 time=144 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=11 ttl=49 time=189 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=12 ttl=49 time=146 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=13 ttl=49 time=144 ms
64 bytes from lb-140-82-112-4-iad.github.com (140.82.112.4): icmp_seq=14 ttl=49 time=159 ms
^C
--- github.com ping statistics ---
52 packets transmitted, 12 received, 76% packet loss, time 51795ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 139.745/639.613/3087.449/922.711 ms, pipe 4
```

example of ping in github site

All services of google work fine but theys are in ipv6 connection

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to provide an answer with so few information. I would required to know what connection speed is your router showing (in the admin panel, normally at 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.0.1) and what's the speed of your wifi connection and many other details...

But I can tell but your ping, that the first 3 packets received had very high latency. That could mean that your network was in high use (windows downloading a patch, the antivirus, may be a playstation updating, an smart tv updating, you downloading things when doing the test, etc...)
However, your ping tends to make me believe that the problem is that the Wifi signal to your laptop is weak.

Try to connect an Ethernet cable directly to the router and disable the Wifi and repeat the ping. If you have 0% packets loss and good latency, the problem is in your Wifi.
You can also repeat the test with your laptop next to the router. Again, if you have no packet loss, probably you've too much distance or obstacles between the router and the laptop.
If your router shares two Wifis, one 2.4 ang another 5G try switching to the other to see if it works better for you.

Comment: Nothing was updating at the time. The speed of my connection is 120 mb. The problem is that for some reason the sites that are ipv4 rarely connect, I have a lot of packet loss on them. And apparently ipv6 is OK. When I change the network my internet works normally, this problem is unique with the wifi router in my house. For example at work I can use it normally

Comment: You should try next to your router. If it is just a Wifi router problem you can use a mesh wifi solution like the one from Google.